# Set elevation of 2.0 meter above cells when running grass r.horizon second method

Tags: grass-gis

I am using the algorithm `r.horizon` second method, it takes a raster, start azimuth angle, end, step size etc. and calculate the horizon altitude angles for each pixel, each azimuth has own layer.

From documentation:

> The calculation method is based on the method used  in  r.sun  to
> calculate  shadows.  It starts  at  a  very  shallow angle and walks
> along the line of sight and asks at each step whether the line of
> sight "hits" the terrain. If so, the angle is increased to  allow  the
> line  of  sight to pass just above the terrain at that point.  This is
> continued until the line of sight reaches a height that is higher than
> any point in the  region  or  until  it reaches  the  border  of  the
> region (see also the bufferzone,e_buff, n_buff, s_buff, and w_buff).
> The the number of lines of sight (azimuth  directions)  is  determined
> from  the direction  and  step  parameters. The method takes into
> account the curvature of the Earth whereby remote features will seem
> to be lower than they actually are. It also accounts for the changes
> of angles towards cardinal directions caused by the projection (see
> above).

and here [r.horizon](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/r.horizon.html)

In method one for single point, one could assign source and target elevation above dem, usually 1.6 m above source point (average tall of human).

My question is how to assign such elevation above each cell before the calling method two of `r.horizon`.
If there is no direct method to pass such parameter as I see, can I edit some script on local PC to assign a default height of 1.6 meters above cells before running the algorithm?